# Is it possible to fetch POST request with REACT useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch

I have a from with an input type file. I want to upload an image to backend to folder upload/images. With submit form (with button) everything is working. No problem.

NO! I want to make it when onChange until submitting form. When I submit form, I just want to patch path of image to user. My question, with useEffect, is it possible to send request POST to backend?

Answer (score 0):

You can use On change function in your input field and and send to server using post request.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

useEffect works when the component is created. If you wanna send a request while components create, yes you can. Just create a function with useCallback and call that function inside useEffect.

[useEffect guide](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useeffect.asp)